# What is the maximum output current for a practical operational amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, solid-state-devices

We have been given a table of electrical characteristics containing the values for the ideal and practical values of operational amplifiers but it does not include the maximum output current. What is the maximum output current for a practical operational amplifier? What I mean by practical is typical value. Thank you.

Comment: Go to a distributor's website (Digikey, Mouser,...) and look at the datasheets for several op-amps.

Comment: What is the typical weight of an animal?

Comment: OPA541 is pretty much the limit.

Comment: Parallel them, the sky is the limit... (well almost)

Answer (score 1):

"Practical" is mostly a question of "how much do you want to pay."

Most op amps are limited to mA or 10s of mA.

[But, you can get really high powered ones if you want (or need) them.](http://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/op-amps/power/overview.html)

That link has op amps for high voltage (100V and more) and high current (like, 10A.)

More typically, you can use a pair of transistors inside the feedback loop of an opamp to provide high current outputs.

That would look something like this:

[image]

(Image from here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-buffer-an-op-amp-output-for-higher-current-part-2/)